# How to get version from package.json in angular library

Tags: angular, typescript

I can't include version from `package.json` in angular's library but it works in a project. I use import like that:

```
import { version } from '../../package.json';
```

and get the following error:

```
ERROR: error TS6059: File '/Users/.../library/package.json' is not under 'rootDir' '/Users/.../library/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

An unhandled exception occurred: error TS6059: File '/Users/.../library/package.json' is not under 'rootDir' '/Users/.../library/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

See "/private/var/folders/tw/z8v0wkt50g5876740n99hzy00000gp/T/ng-0JDpjC/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

The way through `require` includes the whole `package.json` which incur security risks. `import { version } from '../../package.json'` includes only the version number but works for angular applications not libraries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display the app version in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34907682/how-to-display-the-app-version-in-angular)

Comment: Unfortunately not, I'm aware about that way but it doesn't for angular libraries.

Comment: This solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63294323
Consider `resolveJsonModule` needs to be added to `tsconfig.app.json`, not `tsconfig.json`.

Answer (score 5):

You can import it like a regular module:

```js
import { version } from 'package.json'
```

But be sure to add `"resolveJsonModule": true` to `compilerOptions` inside your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: As of angular 10, consider `resolveJsonModule` needs to be added to `tsconfig.app.json`, not to `tsconfig.json`

Comment: I'm in Angular 6 and using this approach yields an issue with doing the build-prod or aot. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58931483/error-building-with-ng-build-prod-fine-without-prod-flag-and-ng-serve

Comment: Getting this error: Should not import the named export 'version' (imported as 'version') from default-exporting module (only default export is available soon)

Answer (score 1):

What about this code :

```
const packageJson = require('../../package.json');
console.log(packageJson.version);
```

Comment: The way through `require` includes the whole `package.json` which incur security risks. `import { version } from '../../package.json'` includes only the version number but works for angular applications not libraries.

Answer (score 0):

As Jozef mentioned make sure you turn on the "resolveJsonModule": true in your tsconfig.json.

```html
import libraryPackage from '../path/to/package/package.json';
```

Another old solution is to make an http call and load the `package.json` file content. This can be useful when your file content dynamically changes (example your deploy server updates the file content when it gets deployed).