# resolveJsonModule not functioning with Angular 10?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

I have a basic JSON file in my assets folder of a brand new Angular 10 project.
Angular CLI: 10.0.1
Node: 14.5.0
OS: win32 x64  TSC version 3.9.5.
In my tsconfig.json I have

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
```

I have restarted vscode multiple times, and tried compiling from the vscode terminal, a powershell window, and a bash terminal, all returning the same message: "Consider using '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json' extension".  I have tried compiling with multiple combinations of different options.  At this point I'm wondering if I should restart this project and simply downgrade my version of Angular?

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you resolve it?

Answer (score 31):

In Angular version 10 we have 3 "tsconfig" files.

You have to add `resolveJsonModule` and `esModuleInterop` options in the `tsconfig.json` file inside the `compilerOptions`.

The file should look like this:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

**Update:** It should be added to `tsconfig.json` not to `tsconfig.app.json`!

Answer (score 20):

If anyone has something similar in Angular 11:

I got this additional error message:

> Cannot find module 'nameOfMyJsonFile.json'. Consider using
> '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json' extension.

So I had to add **resolveJsonModule** to **"tsconfig.json"** file inside **compilerOptions**, NOT in **tsconfig.app.json**.

```
 {
      "compileOnSave": false,
      "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "es2015",
        "module": "es2020",
        "lib": [
          "es2018",
          "dom"
        ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: Do you know if this is an error in the code editor or an error by Angular itself? At compile time this doesn't seem to be an issue and simply gets ignored.

Comment: I'm not sure. I think it was Angular itself because I use the same editor every time and that was the first time I got an error like that. I'm sure it wasn't just a warning because if I could have ignored it, I would, but I somehow got here instead.

Comment: Works for Angular 12. It is not the IDE complaining, it does not compile.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue running Ionic 5 (Angular 12) tests. Solved it with:

```
import * as SomeJsonObjectName from './assets/someObject.json
```

but only after adding

```
"resolveJsonModule": true,
```

to the *compilerOptions* of tsconfig.json

Comment: Works for me without `"esModuleInterop": true`

Answer (score 4):

I found that one solution to Melvin Gruschow's problem (error occuring even with "resolveJsonModule" and "esModuleInterop") is to declare the json module within a file named 'json-typings.d.ts' in the 'app' directory. Such that:

```
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

Comment: only this one worked for me, adding everything others said to tsconfig.json didn't work

Comment: worked for me too :) thanks a lot! should the json file be included under `include` or `rootDirs` in `tsconfig.json` ?  @dean-smith @matija-glujak

Comment: You need TypeScript 2.9 or newer to use the import statement.